Is binning discrete variables a good idea?
This is a follow-up question to

What is the benefit of breaking up a continuous predictor variable?
Is binning of continuous data always bad for statistical tests? [duplicate]

From the above mentioned questions, it looks like that binning continuous variables is not a good idea, due to information loss when binning.
Can the risks associated with binning continuous variables be applied to discrete variables as well?
For example, are the limitations of binning continuous variables for the chi-square test also relevant when working with discrete data?

The binning procedure is intended to discretize the variable. How would one bin already discrete data?  Do you mean combining groups?

yes, combine groups

Do you mean going from something like 10, 11, …, 48, 49, to [10, 19], [20, 29], [30, 39], [40, 49]?

Yes, this is what I think about "combining groups"

It seems like every argument here would then apply, no?
